# Pushing array in functions

Tags: php

So I have this function

```
function parse_records($html) {
    foreach($html->find('li.vcard') as $vcard):
        $table = array();  
        foreach($vcard->find('span.given-name') as $given_name):                    
            $table['given_name'] = (trim(addslashes($given_name->plaintext), " "));
        endforeach; 
        foreach($vcard->find('span.family-name') as $family_name):
            $table['family_name'] = (trim(addslashes($family_name->plaintext)," "));
        endforeach;
        foreach($vcard->find('span.location') as $location):
            $table['location'] = (trim(addslashes($location->plaintext), " "));
        endforeach;
        foreach($vcard->find('span.industry') as $industry):
            $table['industry'] = (trim(addslashes($industry->plaintext), " "));
        endforeach;
        foreach($vcard->find('dd.current-content') as $headline):
            $table['headline'] = (trim(addslashes($headline->plaintext), " "));
        endforeach;
        foreach($vcard->find('a.btn-primary') as $url):
            $table['url'] = addslashes($url->href);
        endforeach;
        return $table;
    endforeach;
```

In my main file I'm using it like this.

```
$page = curl_request($fn, $ln);
$records = parse_records($page);
print_r($records);
```

But it's only for 1 record. What should I modify so I could pass the whole records that being passed?. I've tried `(trim(addslashes($given_name->plaintext), " "))`, but to no avail.

Comment: I think you need another `foreach` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append your array like this:

```
function parse_records($html) {

    // Array to hold all records
    $table = array();  

    foreach($html->find('li.vcard') as $vcard):

        // New array for each record
        $row = array();

        foreach($vcard->find('span.given-name') as $given_name):                    
            $row['given_name'] = (trim(addslashes($given_name->plaintext), " "));
        endforeach; 
        foreach($vcard->find('span.family-name') as $family_name):
            $row['family_name'] = (trim(addslashes($family_name->plaintext)," "));
        endforeach;
        foreach($vcard->find('span.location') as $location):
            $row['location'] = (trim(addslashes($location->plaintext), " "));
        endforeach;
        foreach($vcard->find('span.industry') as $industry):
            $row['industry'] = (trim(addslashes($industry->plaintext), " "));
        endforeach;
        foreach($vcard->find('dd.current-content') as $headline):
            $row['headline'] = (trim(addslashes($headline->plaintext), " "));
        endforeach;
        foreach($vcard->find('a.btn-primary') as $url):
            $row['url'] = addslashes($url->href);
        endforeach;

        // Add row to table
        $table[] = $row;

    endforeach;

    // wait till the end to return the whole thing
    return $table;
}
```

The key lines are each of the `vcard` foreachs creates an array called $row and then at the end of that loop we add that whole row onto the table with `$table[] = $row;`

Comment: I've tried your code sir, but when i print_r($records) it still gives me 1 record.

Comment: @AjVillalobos then you have another problem with your code unrelated to the array appending. Maybe your `$html->find('li.vcard')` isn't returning what you're expecting

Comment: http://pastebin.com/N4wtsir6 - That is the original code before i started refactoring. And it gets all the li.vcard for the page.

Comment: Sir it worked. I misspelled the variable names! thanks so much.

Comment: Yes thanks sir. Now my problem is inserting them. Do i need a loop for it?. `While ($i; $i<count[$i]; $i++)` like that? or...

Comment: Ok got it too! Just `foreach($records as $person):` then just loop there :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it only returns one record is that you have the line `return $table;`. What this means it that you code executes all of the stuff in the `foreach` loop, and then when it hits the `return` statement it **returns that value from the function** - i.e., stops executing from the function.

Assuming you want a list of **each** `$table` generated from each `$vcard`, you would need to do something like this:

```
function parse_records($html)
{
    $tablesList = array();

    foreach($html->find("li.vcard") as $vcard)
    {
        $table = array();

        // Add keys to the table like you are doing.

        $tablesList[] = $table; // Add this table to the tables list.
    }

    // Return the list of all of the tables we produced.

    return $tablesList;
}
```

In this case, I'm adding each `$table` array your loop produces to an array called `$tablesList`, and then I'm returning the whole list of tables - instead of just the first `$table` that gets produced.

Comment: I've tried your's too, but like the sir below same result. And it seems your codes are the same, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I would ask 1) are you sure that your `return` statement is NOT inside the `foreach` loop? I would recommend `{` and `}` as they are easier to read (IMO) than the `endforeach;` method, and 2) what does `print_r($html->find("li.vcard"))` print out?